# Scaling a kite, effect on area

Tags: area

> What happens to the area of a kite if you double the length of ONE of the diagonals?
>
> What happens to the area of a kite if you double the length of BOTH diagonals?

Comment: What??? The title and body don't match at all. Also, no work...please show some.

Comment: Break it into two triangles & think about what would happen if you doubled the base and/or perpendicular height. Your title & question did make laugh ... two questions for the price of one ... you wiley thing !

Comment: Rearranged but still needs more explanation and at least some idea of motivation. I think the "two questions for the price of one" is OK here, they are closely linked.

Comment: 2* or 4*, this is the question!

Comment: It's two questions, and i know the answer, if you double the length of one of the diagonals, it'll double the area. If you double the length of both of them, it'll quadruple ( i think). I just need an example or something, any help will be amazing, it's due tonight... I'm sorry i wasn't so clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

The area of the kite is half the product of the diagonals. (divide the kite into 4 triangles)

If you double one diagonal, you get twice the area.

If you double both diagonals you get 4 times the area.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the kite into 4 right triangle

1. Double the length of ONE diagonals: Each triangle has 1 side remain the same and 1 side double(not including the hypotenuse). So the area of each triangle and also the kite is double.
2. Double the length of BOTH diagonals: Each triangle has 2 sides double(not including the hypotenuse). So the area of each triangle and also the kite is 4 times bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Kite area $=\dfrac{ d_1 \cdot d_2}{2}$.

If one diagonal is doubled, its area doubles. If both are doubled, then area is 4 times bigger.

*And,* this happens even though the diagonals do not bisect each other... ok if they are only orthogonal.